# Как изменить свойства элемента при hover на соседний

Tags: css

Добрый день. Кто знает как можно изменить свойства элемента при `hover` на соседний. Вот пример кода:

```css
/*вот стили(это scss)*/

.nav__list {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: red;
  }
}

.nav__drop_list {
  // background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  width: 165px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  &-w1 {
    width: 185px;
  }
  &-w2 {
    width: 210px;
  }
  &+.nav__link {
    background: red;
  }
}

.nav__drop_item {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.nav__drop_link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: "OpenSans-bold", sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.nav__item:hover .nav__drop_list {
  display: block;
}

.nav__drop_list:hover+.nav__link {
  background: red;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav__list">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link" id="nav__link">Спорт</a>
    <ul class="nav__drop_list" id="nav__drop_list">
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Пресс</a></li>
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Спина</a></li>
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Ягодицы</a></li>
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Ноги</a></li>
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Руки</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Питание</a>
    <ul class="nav__drop_list nav__drop_list-w1">
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Рецепты</a></li>
      <li class="nav__drop_item"><a href="#" class="nav__drop_link">Рацион</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Надо, чтобы при `hover` на выпадающем меню - `.nav__drop_list` менялся `background` у `.nav__link`. Я пробовал  через `js` или через `.nav__drop_list:hover + .nav__link`, но безуспешно.
 В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `+` действует на последующий элемент, а в вашей верстке `.nav__link` предшествует `.nav__drop_list:hover`,  поэтому CSS и не сработал. Покажите скрипт, которым пробовали их увязать.

Comment: добавил стили. А еще пробовал через js вот как то так(хоть и коряво - var bg = document.getElementById('nav__link');
document.getElementById('nav__drop_list').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){bg.style.background = "#ff0000",bg.style.color = "#fff";this.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){bg.style.background = "transparent";});
});

Comment: айдишники только добавлял еще к элементам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` действует на последующий элемент, а в вашей верстке `.nav__link` предшествует `.nav__drop_list`,  поэтому CSS и не сработал.

https://webref.ru/css/selector/adjacent

> `E + F { Описание правил стиля }`
>   Стиль при такой записи применяется к элементу F, но только в том случае, если он является соседним для элемента E и следует сразу после него.

У вас оба блока находятся внутри `.nav__item`. Можно этим воспользоваться:

```
.nav__item:hover .nav__link { ... }
```

Comment: Спасибо бро!Я как то даже и не подумал в ту сторону. Все работает. +1 к ауре добра тебе!-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('.nav__drop_list').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
document.querySelector('.nav__item').style.background = 'red'
})

document.querySelector('.nav__drop_list').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
document.querySelector('.nav__item').style.background = 'transparent'
})
```

```html
<li class="nav__item">
nav__item
</li>

<ul class="nav__drop_list">
nav__drop_list
</ul>
```

Вариант CSS

```css
.nav__drop_list:hover~.nav__item {
  background: red;
}


/* css такое можно реализовать только если изменяемый элемент находиться ниже*/

.nav__item:hover~.nav__drop_list {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav__item">
  nav__item
</li>

<ul class="nav__drop_list">
  nav__drop_list
</ul>
```

Comment: ТОже вариант. Хотя голым css будет правильнее мне кажется. Но спасибо что откликнулся

Comment: Ну ты и сказал...))))  Голым CSS это не реализовать ни как

Comment: Если на странице несколько пар таких блоков, то скрипт перекрасит все `.nav__item` при наведении на любой из `.nav__drop_list`.

Comment: Как-никак, а получилось. Добавил .nav__item:hover .nav__link и все работает как надо

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, а ты про циклы ничего не слышал...?  )))

Answer (score 0):

Стили в CSS  могут действовать на сам элемент:

```
.nav__drop_list {..}
```

на его чайлдов:

```
.nav__drop_list .nav__drop_link {...}
```

и на его "младших братьев" ("соседей"), то бишь элементы, являющиеся чайлдами того же парента и находящиеся ПОСЛЕ данного элемента:

```
.nav__drop_list + .foo {...}
.nav__drop_list ~ .bar {...}
```

Ваш же элемент `.nav__link` по этой генеалогической классификации является для элемента `.nav__drop_list` "старшим братом" и на него с помощью CSS подействовать нельзя. Так что или яваскриптом, или сделать финт ушами вроде этого:

1. поменять местами элементы `.nav__drop_list` и `.nav__link`
2. приделать стиль `.nav__drop_list:hover + .nav__link {...}`
3. расположить визуально оба элемента в нужном порядке с помощью `flex-order`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но flexы мне тут не подойдут..Есть причины со стилизацией связанные. В остальном все верно, я что-то запамятовал просто эти основы..